# How to setup Eclipse for building a multiple project application?

Tags: eclipse, apk, projects

I have a workspace with 6 projects.  All of the projects except the main one, are marked as libraries.

I need to configure the main project to build without build path errors and to include the jars of the other 5 in the apk.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to produce a runtime jar with the other libs rolled in I suggest you look at maven to manage your dependencies and builds.

Comment: I am looking to have an apk with the other jars or classes rolled in.  According to http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html  this should be doable in Eclipse, but it is not working.  When I added the library projects to the main project, try to build and come back to the properties/Android setting, that box is empty again.  Also the generated apk does not contain the other jars.  (I've looked in the apk with jar -tv < *.apk)